# find duplicates and make other cells null except the first one. pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with duplicates values in one column:

| A | description |
| --- | --- |
| First | hello |
| Second | hello |
| Third | hello |
| Fourth | why |
| Fifth | why |

I want that only first duplicate value remain while other become Nan.

Desired output is

| A | description |
| --- | --- |
| First | hello |
| Second | Nan |
| Third | Nan |
| Fourth | why |
| Fifth | Nan |

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
df.loc[df['description'].duplicated(), 'description'] = pd.NA # or float('nan')
```

Alternative for **successive** duplicates:

```
m = df['description'].eq(df['description'].shift())
df.loc[m, 'description'] = pd.NA
```

output:

```
        A description
0   First       hello
1  Second        <NA>
2   Third        <NA>
3  Fourth         why
4   Fifth        <NA>
```